# invalid relational operator after 32766 records when using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query with tuple

Tags: java, spring, oracle, syntax-error, jdbctemplate

I am trying to execute the below query with IN clause and passing tuples of number 32767 or more using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query method. But, i am getting below error:

```
In DataAccessException:PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT ID, STATUS FROM ID_DETAILS WHERE (ID, 1) IN ((?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?)..32767 times)  ORDER BY ID, EL_SEQ ASC]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

**This error is NOT thrown when the number of IDs passed is less than or equal to 32766**. Can someone help in this regard

Below is the code used:

```
List<Object[]> ids = getToupleOf(idList); //idList has 32767 or more Long values
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("IDLIST", ids);
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new 
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(
    getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource());

return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(SQLConstants.REFRESH_QUERY, 
                                         parameters,
       new ResultSetExtractor<List<ResponseVO>>() {
        @Override
        public List<ResponseVO> extractData(ResultSet rs)
                throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
            List<ResponseVO> retList = new LinkedList<ResponseVO>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                ResponseVO eachResponse = constructResponseVOFromRS(rs);
                retList.add(eachResponse);
            }
            return retList;
        }
    });
```

Below is the code for getToupleOf():

```
private List<Object[]> getToupleOf(List<Long> idSet){
    List<Object[]> list = new LinkedList<Object[]>();

    idSet.forEach(l->{
        Object[] touple = new Object[2];
        touple[0] = l.longValue();
        touple[1] = 1;
        list.add(touple);
    });

    return list;

}
```

SQLConstants.REFRESH_QUERY we are passing is given below:

```
public static final String REFRESH_QUERY = "SELECT ID, STATUS FROM ID_DETAILS WHERE (ID, 1) IN (:IDLIST) ORDER BY ID, EL_SEQ ASC";
```

Comment: You know that there is the limit on number of parameter in queue?

Comment: May i know what limit on which queue?

Comment: It depends on what DB you use and its configuration. Usually limit is around 1000.

Comment: We are using Oracle and i know the limit of 1000 in IN clause. Hence we are using tuples.

Comment: Limit is on total number, no matter how you use them, And I notice you have `(ID, 1)`, never saw this before. Are you sure that `1` here is allowed?

Comment: Yes it is valid. I have executed the query by sending all the ids and it got successfully executed in SQL Developer. The above error is coming only when method is executed.

Comment: ` SELECT ID, STATUS FROM ID_DETAILS WHERE (ID, 1) IN ((40501,1), (40502,1), (40503,1), (40504,1), (40505,1), (40506,1), (40507,1), (40508,1), (40509,1), (40510,1), (40511,1), (40512,1), (40513,1), (40514,1), (40515,1).., (75499,1), (75500,1))  ORDER BY ID, EL_SEQ ASC `

Comment: If you have less data to process (say 10 ids) is the problem still reproducible?

Comment: No..Until 32766 records, there is no error. It is only happening if the number of ids is more than 32766

Comment: That is your answer. Do not send so many parameters at once. If you need more split it into chunk. PS: if you remove second element of tuple you will be able to query twice as much data in one chunk.

Comment: I need to send all at once. May i know why there is a restriction to allow 32766 ids and why not more than that.

Comment: I don't have answer on why. Probably some buffer size or they use two bytes for parameter index. You can change that number, but looks like you already have it changed yo maximum. So you can't do it this way. PS: you may try to use array parameters, I never did that and don't know will it help or not.

Comment: Thanks @talex. If you have any examples to use via array params, please post the examples. I shall try and will check

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have. You can easily find them in google.